# Set controls DataContext while binding other properties to parent context

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have the following class structure setup.

```
public class Control1
{
   public Control1()
    {
       Control2Model = new Control2();
    }

   public Control2 Control2Model {get; set;}
   public bool IsControlTwoVisible => true;

}
```

In my xaml I have a UserControl called `CustomUserControl` that I want to pass `Control2Model` to. I also want to bind `IsControlTwoVisible` to my `CustomUserControls` `Visibility` property.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Control1">
  <StackPanel>

     <!--Other controls above this-->

    <CustomUserControl
        DataContext="{Binding Control2Model }"
        Visibility="{Binding IsControlTwoVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}" />

  </StackPanel>
 </UserControl>
```

But I get a binding error because `CustomUserControl` cannot find `IsControlTwoVisible` on `Control2Model`.

Is there any way I set `CustomUserControls` context while still having access to `Control1`s properties?

Note I want to avoid moving `IsControlTwoVisible` to `Control2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to not set `DataContext` in the `Control1` but instead to the top Grid inside `CustomUserControl`. By doing that it will solve your problem.

Please refer to below code for reference:

**Control1.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Control1">
  <StackPanel>

     <!--Other controls above this-->

    <CustomUserControl
        Visibility="{Binding IsControlTwoVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}" />

  </StackPanel>
 </UserControl>
```

**CustomUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UWPBlankApp.CustomUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWPBlankApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid  DataContext="{Binding Control2Model}">
       <!--Other controls-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```